# React Module Not Found

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I installed firebase-admin in my React project, and suddenly I am getting a ton (116 to be exact) of "Module Not Found Errors" when loading the page - 'stream', 'util', 'assert', 'url', 'crypto' and the list goes on and on. Not sure what happened. I tried removing firebase-admin from the package.json file, but that did not fix the errors.

Any suggestions? The app was working fine until I installed firebase-admin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it fix your problem:

1. Remove your node_modules folder (`rm -rf node_modules`)
2. `npm cache clean -f`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm install firebase-admin`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it didn't resolve the issue. I rolled back everything and it seems that the following import line was causing all the errors somehow: import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';

Answer (score 0):

The errors seem to stem from the following import line:

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase-admin';
```